# Java - Extremely basic JFileChooser issue

Tags: java, jfilechooser

I'd like to make a JFileChooser that lets the user select any **file OR directory** that contains the word "hello". That is, the following are valid selections:

```
C:\hello\
C:\fun\hello.txt
etc.
```

How can i get this working? I've tried:

```
import java.io.File;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.filechooser.FileFilter;

        JFileChooser f = new JFileChooser();
        f.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_AND_DIRECTORIES);
        f.setFileFilter(new FileFilter() {

            public boolean accept(File file) {
                return file.getAbsolutePath().contains("hello");
            }

            public String getDescription() {
                return "hi";
            }

        });
        f.showOpenDialog(this);
```

but my JFileChooser is blank. That is to say, I can't see folder "fun" in my C:\ at all.

[image]

Comment: See if using `getCanonicalPath()` makes the difference.

Comment: You may be seeing windows-specific behavior. On OS X I see non-matching folders in grey and can traverse them (but not select them).

Comment: How is file type **hi** defined?

Comment: Can you include your relevant imports?

Comment: Changing to getCanonicalPath() doesn't change anything. I've added imports. It is indeed a Windows only issue. And "hi" is simply the description I've provided in the code above.

Comment: I am able to reproduce the problem on my Windows system. No suggestions at the moment.

Comment: Certainly a good thing to try is print what's passed to the filter `accept` method to the console.

Comment: What's being passed to the accept method is fairly clear. Essentially, any listing in the current directory that doesn't contain "hello" is simply not shown in the dialog. This is why nothing in the C:\ drive is showing.

Comment: You require your `JFileChooser` to display some directories that are both selectable and traversable (those with `"hello"` in the name), and other directories that are traversable but not selectable (that is, you can drill down into them).  I'm fairly sure that's not possible with a `JFileChooser`.

Comment: What if I modified it such that if the folder/file contains "hello", then it can ONLY be selected.

Comment: Additionally, what about somehow overriding how the text is rendered. Somehow, on a Mac it is possible and works fine (folders that don't have "hello" in them are just grayed out but still tranversable. Stupid windows!

Comment: The exact code above...you don't get this problem? What version of Java are you using?

Comment: Yes, indeed accept() is behaving correctly, as all code ultimately does. The question is...how can I accomplish what I set out to?

Comment: Well... Please describe what exactly you want to accomplish.  `JFileChooser` works with one directory at a time - not with the entire File System.  So what is the behavior you need? What are your requirements?

Comment: I need ALL directories to be traversible and only directories named "hello" to be choosable. I need only files called "hello" to be displayed and choosable.

Comment: What if you have the following path: `C:\HelloDir\Something1\Something2\hellofile`.  Please describe the desired behavior of File Open dialog box.

Comment: HelloDir would be traversable (through double click) and selectable (by pressing "choose"), Something1 and Something 2 would be traversible, hellofile would be selectable.

Comment: If you do not mind "*dead ends*" then your `accept()` could return `file.isDirectory() || file.getName().toLowerCase().contains("hello");`

Comment: That is incorrect because this means that "something1" is selectable. It should not be selectable, only traversible.

Comment: If directory is not *accepted* you will neither see it nor be able to choose its files and/or sub-directories.  All normal directories are traversable by default.

Comment: Which is why I'm asking the question. The root of the question is: how do I keep a directory to be visible and traversible but not allow it to be a choosable.

Comment: What exactly is *choosable*? How exactly do you "choose" and how is it different from open?

Comment: On a Mac, the button says "Choose", not open. Open is the same as choose.

Comment: What should happen when a user chooses "Hello" directory?

Comment: The open dialog closes and the result is that that was chosen (selectedFile() is the Hello directory)

Comment: OK. I will be posting the solution in a few.  It's not pretty but seems to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to do some additional overriding.

Two custom classes and a runner class.  Give 'em a try.

```
package custom_file_chooser;

import java.io.File;

import javax.swing.filechooser.FileFilter;

public class MyFileFilter extends FileFilter {

    private String filterString;

    public MyFileFilter(String filterString) {
        super();
        this.filterString = filterString;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean accept(File file) {
         return  file.isDirectory() || file.getName().toLowerCase().contains(filterString);
     }

     @Override
     public String getDescription() {
         return filterString + " only";
     }    
}
```

```
package custom_file_chooser;

import java.io.File;

import javax.swing.JFileChooser;

public class MyFileChooser extends JFileChooser {

    private String filterString;

    public MyFileChooser(String filterString) {
        super();
        this.filterString = filterString;

        setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_AND_DIRECTORIES);
        setFileFilter(new MyFileFilter(filterString));
    }

    @Override
    public void approveSelection() {
        File file = this.getSelectedFile();
        if (!file.isDirectory() || file.getName().contains(filterString)) {
            super.approveSelection();           
        }   
    }
}
```

```
package custom_file_chooser;

import java.io.File;

import javax.swing.JFileChooser;

public class CustomFileChooserRunner {


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        MyFileChooser f = new MyFileChooser("hello");
        int result;

        result = f.showOpenDialog(null);

        if (result == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
            File file = f.getSelectedFile();
            System.out.println("You chose to open: " +
                    file.getName() + (file.isDirectory() ? " directory" : " file"));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This solution isn't ideal (the "Open") button is always enabled, however it gets the job done (that is, when "Open" is pressed on an invalid folder/file, the file chooser is not closed). So, thank you :)